# decode content while reading from socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, unicode, utf-8

Assume I read some content from socket in Python
and have to decode it to UTF-8 on-the-fly.

I can not afford to keep all the content in memory,
so I must decode it as I receive and save to file.

It can happen, that I will only receive partial bytes of character,
(€-sign is represented by three bytes for example in Python as '\xe2\x82\xac').

Assume I have received only the first two bytes (\xe2\x82), if I try to decode 
it, I'm getting 'UnicodeDecodeError', as expected.

I could always try to decode the current content and check if it throws an Exception

- But how reliable is this approach?
- How can I know or determine if I can decode the current content?
- How to do it correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guido's time machine strikes again.

```
>>> dec = codecs.getincrementaldecoder('utf-8')()
>>> dec.decode('foo\xe2\x82')
u'foo'
>>> dec.decode('\xac')
u'\u20ac'
```

Comment: It works! Does this decoder keep the state? Otherwise how it knows about already available bytes in it? what about memory consumption?

Do I have to recreate the decoder every period of time?

Comment: It probably stores the undecoded bytes somewhere. With UTF-8 that means that it will store up to 3 bytes. The second argument to `decode()` finalizes the current decode operation and allows you to use `reset()` to recycle it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a combination of [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [codecs.iterdecode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterdecode) (as shown [here](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/10/05/python-unicode-streams/))?

I have created a file full of *€* symbols, and seems to work as expected (although instead of reading from a file, as shown below, you would be reading from your socket):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import codecs
import functools
import sys

with open('stack70.txt', 'rb') as euro_file:
    f_iterator = iter(functools.partial(euro_file.read, 1), '')
    for item in codecs.iterdecode(f_iterator, 'utf-8'):
        print "sizeof item: %s, item: %s" % (sys.getsizeof(item), item)
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I have little experience with `codecs`, so I'm not 100% sure this will do what you want, but (as far as I can tell), it does, right?

`stack70.txt` is the file full of "euro" symbols. The code above outputs:

```
sizeof item: 56, item: €
sizeof item: 56, item: €
sizeof item: 56, item: €
sizeof item: 56, item: €
sizeof item: 56, item: €
```

(done using python 2.7)